# Creating Bell States with CNOT conditioned to the control qubit being set to zero

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, bell-basis

I was using qiskit to generate all of the Bell States. I created the following circuits for each state:

$|\Phi^+\rangle :$

[image]

$|\Phi^-\rangle :$

[image]

$|\Psi^+\rangle :$
[image]

$|\Psi^-\rangle :$
[image]

The $|\Psi^\pm\rangle$ states were creating CNOTs with X gates before, that way we have a CNOT that acts when the control qubit is set to zero.

When I execute the first 3 circuits in Qiskit, I get the expected state vectors. However, when I execute the last one, I get $\frac{(-|01\rangle + |10\rangle)}{\sqrt{2} }$. I can see that the state vector is  $|\Psi^-\rangle$ up to a global phase factor. My question is: Is this a valid method to create Bell States? Or should I stick to the one that uses "normal" CNOT, X and Z?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Please see this thread how to create Bell states: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11700/how-can-you-construct-the-different-two-qubit-bell-states/11701#11701

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you construct the different two-qubit Bell states?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11700/how-can-you-construct-the-different-two-qubit-bell-states)

Comment: This is perfectly fine. A global phase is nothing to be bothered about.

Comment: DaftWullie is right but you can prepare Bell states with one gate less than in case of circuits in the question.